# git: ascii special characteres displayed wrong (inverted ESC)

Tags: gnome-terminal, git

If I enter `git show eab24c62075505a` it looks like this:

[image: git-ascii-wrong]

If I enter `git show eab24c62075505a | less` it looks good.

What could be wrong here?

I use the default terminal of Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

For many people, the desired behavior of a simple `git show eab24c62075505a` is to show it in some pager, e.g. `less` by default; that is, without having to manually redirecting the output. This is achieved by `git` internally calling the pager.

Make sure your pager is `less` (it probably is), and also make sure that this `less` recognizes and handles colors by using its `-R` option. You can achieve the latter by exporting the `LESS` environment variable (e.g. `export LESS=-R`), or by setting `PAGER` or `GIT_PAGER` accordingly, such as `export GIT_PAGER='less -R'`).

Comment: Thank you for your hint. If I use `git show eab24c62075505a | less` there are no broken characters, since git does not output color control characters. I added `-R` to the `LESS` env variable and now it works. Thank you.